# TLS mutual authentication Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, mutual-authentication

I configured TLS mutual configuration for Azure app as describred [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth) using asp.net framework 4.7.2, but the problem that in global.asax application_start my HttpContext is not available i tried both : 
the solution in link :

```
NameValueCollection headers = base.Request.Headers;
```

and the static Httpcontext

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers
```

both returns that HttpContext is not available.
how can i call HttpContext on global.asax application_start or is there a workaround to do ? my application is hosted on azure.

Comment: HttpContext holds information about the current HTTP request. It will only be available when receiving a request. You will have to authenticate every request individually.

Comment: should i allow all paths in the incomming requests and after that i authenticate every request alone , like adding a custom authorization attribute that validate cerfication  ?

Comment: Yes. There is a guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api) that shows you what that attribute may look like.